# How to populate bootstrap typeahead in Handlebars?

Tags: node.js, twitter-bootstrap, meteor, handlebars.js

I need to populate a typeahead field from the Twitter Bootstrap in a Handlebars template (environment: Node.js and Meteor).

Here is the template bit:

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source={{{names}}}>
```

Here is the Javascript bit:

```
Template.myTemplate.names = function () {
    var temp = MyCollection.find({}).map(function (x) { return x.name; });
    var ret = "[\"" + temp.join("\", \"") + "\"]";
    return ret;
};
```

The problem is that the Javascript that is generated is not correct, e.g.,

```
<input type="text" data-provide="typeahead" data-source="["John", " "Albert"]>
```

and does not work. I think I am over-engineering this and there must be a better way to generate/render the Handlebars template...

Comment: Did you try with simple quotes? 
    var temp = MyCollection.find({}).map(function (x) { return "'"+x.name+"'"; });
    var ret = "[" + temp.join(", ") + "]";

Comment: I tried the simple quotes approach. Somehow, the typeahead widget understands only double quotes.

Answer (score 0):

I stumbled upon this while trying to answer a similar question myself.

The double quotes are required because it expects JSON.

Instead of the `ret` string formatting,  I used `JSON.stringify` like this in your example:

```
var ret = JSON.stringify(temp);
```